# How to reuse the rendering actions from nested controllers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, reusability

I have a question regarding the reuse of code among controller actions. I think it is a fairly standard situation, so I am interested in what's the best practice in Rails.

Let's say I have a `films` resource with a corresponding `FilmsController`, which has a nested resource `comments` served by `CommentsController`. The nested resource can be rendered on its own using its `index` and `show` actions. However, it should also be possible to render the comments embedded in the corresponding film page.

Now, the question goes, what is the best way to reuse the code from `CommentsController` within `FilmsController.show`?

1) Force the `CommentsController.index` to render to a string and then pass it in a variable to the film view?

Or 2) call the `CommentsController.index` directly in the film view as a kind of "partial", executing the database queries from there?

Or 3) create a separate method in `CommentsController` responsible for the database handling, call it from both `CommentsController.index` and `FilmsController.show`, and use the corresponding view in both the places, too?

To me the options 1) and 2) seem a bit messy, while 3) is not modular and involves some repeating of code. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: look up the presenter pattern in ruby on rails

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - thanks for the idea, the Presenter pattern may indeed be helpful in some cases, when the passed data are more complex. All in all, it looks like I'm going with my option 3), while making things as encapsulated as possible.

Comment: Simple data has a bad habit of getting unsimple, and quick, but your welcome.

Comment: `create a separate method in CommentsController responsible for the database handling` Database operations should be in the model not the controller. Another thing to look into for database re-use is service objects.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the question goes, what is the best way to reuse the code from CommentsController within FilmsController.show?

You could move the shared controller logic into a inside your application controller (or a lib and require it appropriately), a la:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def foo
    @foo = "foo"
  end

end
```

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :foo, :only => [:index]

  def index    
  end

end
```

Films Controller:

```
class FilmsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :foo, :only => [:show]

  def show
  end

end
```

For repeated view logic you can move that to a common folder, say `your_app/app/views/shared/_foo.html.erb` and render that appropriately.

---

Another option is to place the relevant code into an external module:

**lib/mymodule.rb**

```
module MyModule
  def foo
  end
end
```

And then you can include the module inside your controller or anywhere you want access to your `foo` method.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  include MyModule

    def index
      foo()
    end

end
```

Comment: It is an interesting idea to use a common ancestor for the aggregate controller and its components and I might actually use it for some other aspects. But for this simple issue it seems to make the code more obscure and scattered. It still seems cleaner to me to put the `foo` code in `CommentsController` and call it explicitly.

Comment: Yeah I can speak from experience when I say it's a little tricky to figure out a method is being called from the ApplicationController when debugging. I think a cleaner approach would be to partition the repeated code into a lib module and then include it inside your relevant controller actions. At least that way you have a clear indicator that your method is being called from an external source and you're inheriting inheriting code into controllers that never make use of it.